# How to import xml file in wagtail OR migrate to wagtail from wordpress

Tags: xml, wordpress, import, wagtail

I am trying to migrate wordpress to wagtail and method i am using is to export wordpress to xml and then import xml in wagtail. If i use this command `./manage.py wordpress_to_wagtail blog --xml=export.xml` then command not found error is shown up. Please help me about this and django manangement commands.

Comment: Did you install the wagtail-blog package (https://pypi.org/project/wagtail-blog/)? The `wordpress_to_wagtail` command is part of that package, not Wagtail itself.

Comment: But its still showing same error that command not found

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
python manage.py import_xml path/to/xml/file.xml parent_page_id
```

Also, use the v2API which is more straightfoward as explained in their pypi package. I would recommend you check out their [github](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-wordpress-import#site-url-for-importing-images-and-documents)